# запуск службы delphi

Tags: delphi, служба

Появилась необходимость в создании службы на delphi, почитав инфу в гугле начал писать код, получилось вот что :

```
type
  TService4 = class(TService)
  procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
  end;

var
  Service4: TService4;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  Service4.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TService4.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TService4.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  Started := True;
end;

procedure write();
var
  s:string;
  RC: Cardinal;
  f:textfile;
begin
  assignfile(f,'D:\temp1.txt');
  rewrite(f);
  writeln(f,'123');
  closefile(f);
end;

procedure TService4.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  Stopped := True;
end;

procedure TService4.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(True);
    write();
  end;
end;
```

Но после регистрирования службы и ее запуска на диске D так и не появился желанный файл `temp1.txt`. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: В логах Windows (EventLog -> Applications) есть ошибки какие-нибудь?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov неа, нету [ссылка](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/05/08/0003/1069/205869/69/093669fd59.jpg) насколько я понял, в графе "источник" должен стоять мой exe, его там нет

Comment: добавьте в ваш код функционал, который пишет в EventLog. Логируйте каждый шаг, а после выполнения кода, проверьте, что в логах написано. Вот тут рассказано как писать в EventLog: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397934/writing-to-the-event-log-in-delphi

Comment: @RafaelOsipov странно, но в логах ничего нет [link](https://pastebin.com/05AuVZBs)

Comment: Значит сервис не стартует вообще. Обычно, в таких случаях, должна быть ошибка в `EventLog->Applications`. Проверьте, под какими правами у вас стартует сервис (в свойствах сервиса), и есть-ли у этого пользователя права записи файлов в корень диска D.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov она запускается с системной учетной записью(если вы про это), через консоль еще проверил : D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY). У пользователя есть права на зпись в Д диск, да и сделал, чтоб записывало туда же, где и ехе (C:\Windows\SysWOW64) все равно нет ничего

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58382/discussion-between-lolidze-and-rafael-osipov).

Comment: @RafaelOsipov можете еще что-то посоветовать ?

Comment: я на дельфи писал больше двадцати лет назад, поэтому вряд-ли смогу добавить что-то к тому, что уже сказал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работа вашего сервиса останавливается после достижения вот этой строки:

```
ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(True);
```

т.к. из этого метода, при вызове его с параметром `True`, управление вернётся только после получения команды `Terminate`.

Чтобы всё заработало, вам надо сделать следующее:

- в `ServiceStart` создать и запустить отдельный рабочий поток, который в своём методе `Execute` будет выполнять нужную вам работу (вызывать функцию `write()`)
- в `ServiceExecute` вызывать метод `ServiceThread.ProcessRequests` с параметром `False`
- в `ServiceStop` останавливать и уничтожать рабочий поток.

---

Адаптированный пример, из книги [Dniele Teti - Delphi CookBook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1785287427):

ServiceU.pas:

```
unit ServiceU;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, 
  Winapi.Messages, 
  System.SysUtils, 
  System.Classes, 
  Vcl.Graphics, 
  Vcl.Controls, 
  Vcl.SvcMgr, 
  Vcl.Dialogs, 
  WorkerThreadU;

type
  TSampleService = class(TService)
    procedure ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
    procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
    procedure ServicePause(Sender: TService; var Paused: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceContinue(Sender: TService; var Continued: Boolean);        
  private
    FWorkerThread: TWorkerThread;
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
  end;

{$R *.dfm}    

var
  SampleService: TSampleService;

implementation

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  SampleService.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TSampleService.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TSampleService.ServiceContinue(Sender: TService; var Continued: Boolean);
begin
  FWorkerThread.Continue;
  Continued := True;
end;

procedure TSampleService.ServicePause(Sender: TService; var Paused: Boolean);
begin
  FWorkerThread.Pause;
  Paused := True;
end;

procedure TSampleService.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  FWorkerThread := TWorkerThread.Create(True);
  FWorkerThread.Start;
  Started := True;
end;

procedure TSampleService.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  FWorkerThread.Terminate;
  FWorkerThread.WaitFor;
  FreeAndNil(FWorkerThread);
  Stopped := True;
end;

procedure TSampleService.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(false);
    TThread.Sleep(1000);
  end;
end;

end.
```

WorkerThreadU.pas:

```
unit WorkerThreadU;

interface

uses
  System.Classes;

type
  TWorkerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FPaused: Boolean;    
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    procedure Pause;
    procedure Continue;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, 
  System.IOUtils;

procedure TWorkerThread.Continue;
begin
  FPaused := False;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
var
  ExePath, LogFileName: string;
  Log: TStreamWriter;
begin
  try
    FPaused := False;
    ExePath := TPath.GetDirectoryName(GetModuleName(HInstance));
    LogFileName := TPath.Combine(ExePath, ClassName + '_' + IntToStr(CurrentThread.ThreadID) + '.txt');
    Log := TStreamWriter.Create(TFileStream.Create(LogFileName, fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite));
    try
      while not Terminated do
      begin
        if not FPaused then
        begin
          Log.WriteLine('Message from thread: ' + TimeToStr(now));
        end;
        TThread.Sleep(1000);
      end;
    finally
      Log.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      TFile.WriteAllText(TPath.Combine(ExePath, 'CRASH_LOG.TXT'), E.ClassName + ' ' + E.Message);
    end
  end;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Pause;
begin
  FPaused := True;
end;

end.
```

Comment: сделал, как вы и написали, но проблема осталась [link](https://pastebin.com/REYJH5ca) скорее всего, я чтот упустил, можете тыкнуть носом ? спасибо

Comment: @Lolidze Используйте шаблонный код, что я привёл в ответе. И никогда не используйте `AssignFile`, т.к. это технология 90-х.

Comment: у меня нет модуля IOUtils в delphi 7, и такие методы, как TPath,TFile и тп отпадают, а без них - это все равно что и бывший мой код, где я использовал AssignFile и особо отличий не вижу.

Comment: @Lolidze Во-первых, пользуйтесь современными версиями `Delphi` (вы же не используете Windows 95 до сих пор?). Во-вторых, отличий от вашего кода очень даже много, но раз вы хотите идти своим путём и игнорируете пример, то учитесь тогда дебажить свой код и тренируйте умение искать отличия между тем, что пишите вы и тем, что написано в примере. Ну и в-третьих, проблема может быть ещё и в окружении/правах доступа/погоды на Марсе. Вы видите свой сервис в Диспетчере задач? Вы уверены, что он вообще стартует и что ему разрешено писать туда, куда вы хотите?

Comment: не поймите не правильно, я сюда как раз и пишу из-за незнания, и прошу Вашей помощи. `Во-вторых, отличий от вашего кода очень даже много` пожалуйста, объясните в чем именно ? я вижу, что в примере поток вынесен в другой файл и создание файлов лога происходит через TStreamWriter, который, к сожалению, не встроен в delphi 7. Сервис запускается с системной учетной записью(если вы про это), так же добавлял и отдельно для своей учетной записи, через консоль еще проверил : D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)

Comment: А вы видите, чем отличается метод `ServiceExecute` от вашего? Если сделать так, как у вас, то при старте сервис начнёт отжирать 100% CPU (одного из его ядер). Код в юните `ServiceU.pas` полностью совместим с Delphi 7 и там нету лишних строчек, которые можно выбросить. Код же `WorkerThreadU.pas` легко адаптируется для Delphi 7 *без изменения логики*. Обратите внимание на обработку ошибок и на то, что для записи в файл используется *абсолютный путь*. А вопрос, наблюдаете ли вы свой сервис в Диспетчере задач, вы так и оставили подвисшим в воздухе.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то должно быть примерно так [link](https://pastebin.com/pHu61yFb) . В диспетчере задач сервис отображается, после запуска стоит статус "выполняется"

Comment: @Lolidze Да, примерно. Только обработка ошибок с использованием `Log` сделана неправильно. Плюс, в таком варианте, лог у вас должен появиться только после того, как вы остановите службу.

Comment: Не подскажите, чем можно заменить  TStreamWriter в delphi 7 ? да и TFile, ибо, я так понимаю, что в нем и заключается вся суть. После остановки службы тхт так и не появился ((

Comment: ServiceExecute не нужен в данном случае, раз вся логика вынесена в доп.поток.